# perl matched keywords and modify the keywords

Tags: regex, perl

I set an environment variable X first.

```
> setenv X "abc 12_3 abc"
```

Then I wrote a regex in perl trying to match the first column along with a space and the remaining string  too in $2.
here I print the first match $1

```
> echo $X|perl -lne '$_=~m/([^\s]*[\s])(.*)/;print $1'
abc
```

here I print the second match $2.

```
> echo $X | perl -lne '$_=~m/([^\s]*[\s])(.*)/;print $2'
12_3 abc
```

Till now as it looks everything is OK.
Now I thought of replacing all the underscore in the second match to spaces

```
> echo $X | perl -lne '$_=~m/([^\s]*[\s])(.*)/;$2=~s/_/ /g;'
Modification of a read-only value attempted at -e line 1, <> line 1.
```

well the error message says that $2 is read only.thats fine.
so I copy $2 to some temporary variable $temp.
so while copying its fine and $1 and $2 still exists as seen below:

```
> echo $X | perl -lne '$_=~m/([^\s]*[\s])(.*)/;$temp=$2;print $1.$2'
abc 12_3 abc
```

Now I tried replacing underscores with spaces in the temporary string $temp.

```
> echo $X | perl -lne '$_=~m/([^\s]*[\s])(.*)/;$temp=$2;$temp=~s/_/ /g;print $1.$2'

>
```

My question is where are $1 and $2 gone?
even though I made changes to $temp if its changing $2 what happened to atleast $1?

Answer (score 10):

the statement `$temp=~s/_/ /g` resets the match variables; so if you want to use then after a new match/substitution, you'll have to store then in a variable...

Comment: But WHy did that resetting happen?

Comment: @sarathi The variables `$1` and `$2` are temporary variables that refer to the last pattern match attempted. Each new match or substitution overwrites previous matches. Otherwise you could never reliably use them more than once per script.

Comment: @sarathi _"Capture group contents are dynamically scoped and available to you outside the pattern until the end of the enclosing block or until the next successful match, whichever comes first"._ [Capture Groups](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups).

Answer (score 1):

`s/_/ /g` was successful, and it contains no captures, so it set all capture variables to undef.

This code will do what you want:

```
perl -nle'($x,$y)=/^(\S*\s+)(.*)/; $y =~ s/_/ /g; print $1.$2;'
```

Or even:

```
perl -ple's/^\S*\s+\K(.*)/ ($x=$1) =~ s{_}{ }g; $x /e;'
```

Or even (5.14+):

```
perl -ple's/^\S*\s+\K(.*)/ $1 =~ s{_}{ }gr /e;'
```